# Finding a general solution to a first-order difference equation

Tags: recurrence-relations, exponentiation

so I can solve some simple difference equations (those with a constant inhomogeneous segment), but I have come across one that I don't know how to deal with. Please see the attached image.

An example of an equation I am having trouble with and one that I can do already.

[image]
My biggest issue is how to tackle the (1/6)^n

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

> An example of an equation I am having trouble with: $\;\displaystyle x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{6} x_n + \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^n$
>
> ... and one that I can do already: $\;\displaystyle x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{6} x_n + \frac{1}{6}$

Multiply the first equation ("*having trouble with*") by $6^{n+1}\,$:

$$
6^{n+1}x_{n+1} = 6^n x_n + 6
$$

Let $\,y_n = 6^n x_n\,$, then the above reduces to:

$$
y_{n+1} = y_n + 6
$$

The latter is of the kind "*that I can do already*" (it's actually an arithmetic progression in this case). Solve it for $\,y_n\,$, then you get $\displaystyle\,x_n = \frac{1}{6^n} y_n\,$.

Comment: The issue is, (which I probably should have mentioned before), is that I'm trying to solve it using the Principle of Superposition. @dxiv

Comment: @Curious Once you reduced the problem to the case you know, you can solve that one in whatever way you prefer. By superposition for example, the general soultion of the homogeneous recurrence $y_{n+1} = y_n$ is $y_n=C\,$, and a particular solution of the non-homogeneous recurrence is $y_n=6n\,$, so the general solution will be $y_n = 6n + C\,$.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to try with an inhomogeneous term of the form $r^n$ is a constant times $r^n$.  But if $r^n$ itself is a solution of the homogeneous equation, the next thing to try is a constant times $n r^n$.

Comment: So for example: D*r^n     or    D*nr^n, if need be?